# Backbone.js filter collection by name

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following collection:

```
[ { name: "sally" }, { name: "john" } , { name: "harry" } ]
```

I would like to filter by name even if the name is contained inside.

for example:

If I'm filtering by 's' I would like it to catch { name: "sally" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone uses the Underscorejs, so the filter from underscore works on the backbone collections.

if your collection is a backbone collection.

```
  var publishedBooks = books.filter(function(item) {
       return item.name.indexOf('something') !== -1;
  });
```

Comment: I don't need the exact match, I need to if what I'm searching is contained inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define a function in your collection that calls `filter`:

```
var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // ...

    filterByName: function(str){
       return this.filter(function(item) {
           return item.get("name").indexOf(str) > -1;
      });
    }
});
```

Then you can call `myCollection.filterByName("s")` to get what you want.